# 16-QAM modulation and demodulation - missing one line in the graph

Tags: matlab, signal-processing, wireless

I am trying to do modulation and demodulation for 16-QAM and then trying to compare theoretical and simulated BER.

I am **not** getting `simulation`-line in the graph.
[image: Missing the <simulation>-line]

I can not understand what is wrong with my code. Can anybody help me?

here is the code:

```matlab
M=16;
SNR_db = [0 2 4 6 8 10 12];
x = randi([0,M-1],1000,1);
hmod = modem.qammod(16);
hdemod = modem.qamdemod(hmod,'SymbolOrder', 'Gray');
tx = zeros(1,1000);
for n=1:1000
    tx(n) = modulate(hmod, x(n));
end
rx = zeros(1,1000);
rx_demod = zeros(1,1000);
for j = 1:7
    err = zeros(1,7);
    err_t = zeros(1,7);
    for n = 1:1000
        rx(n) = awgn(tx(n), SNR_db(j));
        rx_demod(n) = demodulate(hdemod, rx(n));

        if(rx_demod(n)~=x(n))
            err(j) = err(j)+1;
        end
    end
    % err_t = err_t + err;
end
theoryBer = 3/2*erfc(sqrt(0.1*(10.^(SNR_db/10))));
figure
semilogy(SNR_db,theoryBer,'-',SNR_db, err, '^-');
grid on
legend('theory', 'simulation');
xlabel('Es/No, dB')
ylabel('Symbol Error Rate')
title('Symbol error probability curve for 16-QAM modulation')
```

Comment: Sorry, can you be more specific with your problem? I can execute your code and there is a figure there. I cant see any problem actually!

Comment: I can see this: http://img401.imageshack.us/img401/5017/so1w.png

Comment: You are overwriting the error count "err" in each iteration of the loop. Even if you fix that it's not quite right, since err is a count where the demodulated signal doesn't match the transmitted one, while the theoretical curve is in terms of probability.

Comment: The other error you have is that you specify gray coding for the demodulator but not for the modulator.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.dsplog.com/db-install/wp-content/uploads/2008/06/script_16qam_gray_mapping_bit_error_rate.m

That does what you want manually, without assuming any toolbox functionality (i.e. the fancy modulator and demodulators).

Also you can try

> edit commdoc_mod

Make a copy of that file and you should be able to get it to do what you want with one simple loop.

**Edit**

Here are the modifications to that file that give you the simulated EbNo curves instead of the symbol error rate ones.  Should be good enough for any practical purpose.

```
M = 16;                     % Size of signal constellation
k = log2(M);                % Number of bits per symbol
n = 3e4;                    % Number of bits to process
nSyms = n/k;                % Number of symbols

hMod = modem.qammod(M);         % Create a 16-QAM modulator
hMod.InputType = 'Bit';         % Accept bits as inputs
hMod.SymbolOrder = 'Gray';         % Accept bits as inputs
hDemod = modem.qamdemod(hMod);  % Create a 16-QAM based on the modulator

x = randi([0 1],n,1); % Random binary data stream
tx = modulate(hMod,x);

EbNo = 0:10; % In dB
SNR = EbNo + 10*log10(k);

rx = zeros(nSyms,length(SNR));
bit_error_rate = zeros(length(SNR),1);
for i=1:length(SNR)
    rx(:,i) = awgn(tx,SNR(i),'measured');
end
rx_demod = demodulate(hDemod,rx);
for i=1:length(SNR)
    [~,bit_error_rate(i)] = biterr(x,rx_demod(:,i));
end

theoryBer = 3/(2*k)*erfc(sqrt(0.1*k*(10.^(EbNo/10))));
figure;
semilogy(EbNo,theoryBer,'-',EbNo, bit_error_rate, '^-');
grid on;
legend('theory', 'simulation');
xlabel('Eb/No, dB');
ylabel('Bit Error Rate');
title('Bit error probability curve for 16-QAM modulation');
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you confuse Symbol Error Probability and Bit Error Probability. Moreover `err = zeros(1,7);` is misplaced.

After the corrections:

```
M=16;
SNR_db = 0:2:12;
N=1000;
x = randi([0,M-1],N,1);
k = log2(M); % bits per symbol

tx = qammod(x, M,'Gray');
err = zeros(1,7);
for j = 1:numel(SNR_db)
    rx = awgn(tx, SNR_db(j),'measured');
    rx_demod = qamdemod( rx, M, 'Gray' );
    [~,err(j)] = biterr(x,rx_demod);
end

theorySER = 3/2*erfc(sqrt(0.1*(10.^(SNR_db/10))));

figure
semilogy(SNR_db,theorySER,'-',SNR_db, err*k, '^-');
grid on
legend('theory', 'simulation');
xlabel('Es/No, dB')
ylabel('Symbol Error Rate')
title('Symbol Error Probability curve for 16-QAM modulation')
```

And the resulting graph is:
[image]